# Resttemplate - failed to connect: timeout I should not be here

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm getting this json response with some timeout message in the beginning and the class throwing Not valid jSON exception.

Json Response

```
failed to connect: timeout I should not be here {Valid json}
```

but when I test through postman , I don't see that frustrating message.

I'm using spring RestTemplate` to call the service

```
final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    final ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toUriString(),
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Even though I increase timeout values, it's the same

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
        protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
            return false;
        }
    });

}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(10000);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    return factory;
}
```

This is my camel route

```
    from("direct:processRequest").process(new RecipientListBean()).recipientList(header("recipients"))
            .aggregationStrategy(aggregationStrategy)
            .parallelProcessing()
            .to("bean:transformerBean");
```

Comment: Are you seeing timeouts when making a single request or when running a load test?

Comment: it's a single request, I'm getting response in less than  5 secs but still I see that message, I don't know what is  the default timeout my service has@ootero